# I have a set of latest emojis in a sentence that I am appending to a list in python, which while appending is getting converted to unicode

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, emoji

I need the emojis to be as it is and not get converted to unicode.

input string: 'I am having positive vibe '

output list: ['I','am','having','positive','vibe','\U0001faf0\U0001faf0\U0001faf0\U0001faf0\U0001faf0']

I tried using emoji library and used the emojize function to convert it to emoji format. Also tried using the string.encode function to convert it to emoji. Both of them did not work in this case.

Comment: It's just representation, they *are* Unicode characters.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [ask]. Then, [edit] your question to provide a [mcve].

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to decode the unicode. That's just a simple representation of those emojis.

For example:

```
a = ''
b = a.encode('utf-8') # Encode
b is some code. Here The emoji gets converted to a byte object.

c = b.decode('utf-8') # Decode
c is '' # Result
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: But when appending to the list, it gets added as unicode not in the picture format.